# How can i connect Buttons from my Index.html to my Unity Code

Tags: javascript, c#, html, unity-game-engine, webgl

`I have a Unity 3D Project where i can drive around with a forklift and i want to add features like picking stuff up, putting it down and colorize materials. But I have a problem with connecting the buttons (which I made in the index.html, which is generated when i run my project with webgl) with my unity code. The webgl page looks like this:
[my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjitC.png)

I already tried it with UnityLoader.instantiate but it does not work for me i get the following error:
[UnityLoader - error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGgSS.png)

Here is the script from my Index.html
`

```
    <script>
      var container = document.querySelector("#unity-container");
      var canvas = document.querySelector("#unity-canvas");
      var loadingBar = document.querySelector("#unity-loading-bar");
      var progressBarFull = document.querySelector("#unity-progress-bar-full");
      var fullscreenButton = document.querySelector("#unity-fullscreen-button");
      var warningBanner = document.querySelector("#unity-warning");

      function unityShowBanner(msg, type) {
        function updateBannerVisibility() {
          warningBanner.style.display = warningBanner.children.length ? 'block' : 'none';
        }
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = msg;
        warningBanner.appendChild(div);
        if (type == 'error') div.style = 'background: red; padding: 10px;';
        else {
          if (type == 'warning') div.style = 'background: yellow; padding: 10px;';
          setTimeout(function() {
            warningBanner.removeChild(div);``
            updateBannerVisibility();
          }, 5000);
        }
        updateBannerVisibility();
      }

      var buildUrl = "Build";
      var loaderUrl = buildUrl + "/build.loader.js";
      var config = {
        dataUrl: buildUrl + "/build.data",
        frameworkUrl: buildUrl + "/build.framework.js",
        codeUrl: buildUrl + "/build.wasm",
        streamingAssetsUrl: "StreamingAssets",
        companyName: "DefaultCompany",
        productName: "warehouseOnline3D",
        productVersion: "0.1",
        showBanner: unityShowBanner,
      };

  
      if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        // Mobile device style: fill the whole browser client area with the game canvas:

        var meta = document.createElement('meta');
        meta.name = 'viewport';
        meta.content = 'width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=yes';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
        container.className = "unity-mobile";

        // To lower canvas resolution on mobile devices to gain some
        // performance, uncomment the following line:
        // config.devicePixelRatio = 1;

        canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
        canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';

        unityShowBanner('WebGL builds are not supported on mobile devices.');
      } else {
        // Desktop style: Render the game canvas in a window that can be maximized to fullscreen:

        canvas.style.width = "960px";
        canvas.style.height = "600px";
      }

      loadingBar.style.display = "block";

      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = loaderUrl;
      script.onload = () => {
        createUnityInstance(canvas, config, (progress) => {
          progressBarFull.style.width = 100 * progress + "%";
        }).then((unityInstance) => {
          loadingBar.style.display = "none";

          fullscreenButton.onclick = () => {
            unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);
          };
        }).catch((message) => {
          alert(message);
        });
      };
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      
      var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Build/webgl.json");
      
      gameInstance.SendMessage("Sideloader", "test", "printed from webgl");  
    </script>
```

[the function that should be called from the UnityLoader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dnj2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way via the `UnityLoader` afaik is from very early Unity WebGL versions.

---

You want to store the result of the `createUnityInstance` within the `then` block and then use it later like

```
<script>
    let instance = null;
    
    ....
    
    createUnityInstance(canvas, config, (progress) => {
          progressBarFull.style.width = 100 * progress + "%";
        }).then((unityInstance) => {
          instance = unityInstance;
    ...
```

then you can later on use it and do

```
instance.SendMessage("Sideloader", "test", "printed from webgl");
```

However you can not do this in the current spot in the script initilazation level. You will have to wait until that `then` block was actually called and then do it for your button e.g.

```
<button onclick='ButtonClick()'>test</button>

...

function ButtonClick()
{
    if(instance) instance.SendMessage("Sideloader", "test", "printed from webgl"); 
}
```

---

As a more complex alternative though you can implement a plugin and let the c# part inject a callback into it you can later call and once your project gets more complex you might want to go with that rather.

E.g. have a `MyFancyPlugin.jslib`

```
var myFancyPlugin = {
{    
    $CallbackPtr : {},

    InitializeJavaScript : function(callbackPtr)
    {
        CallbackPtr = callbackPtr;
    }

    FancyCall : function(value)
    {
        const valueSize = lengthBytesUTF8(value)+1;
        const valueBuffer = _malloc(dataUrlSize);
        stringToUTF8(value, valueBuffer, valueSize);
        Runtime.dynCall("vi", $CallbackPtr, [valueBuffer]);
        free(valueBuffer);
    }
};
autoAddDeps(myFancyPlugin, '$CallbackPtr');
mergInto(LibraryManager.library, myFancyPlugin);
```

and on your button do e.g.

```
<button onclick='FancyCall("TEST!")'>test</button>
```

and then in `c#` have something like e.g.

```
public static class MyFancyPlugin
{
    private delegate void Callback(string value);

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static void InitializeJavaScript(Callback callback);

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        InitializeJavaScript(OnCallbackReceived);
    }

    [MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(Callback))]
    private static void OnCallbackReceived(string value)
    {
        Debug.Log("Received from JavaScript: {value}");
    }
}
```

where something has to call

```
MyFancyPlugin.Initialize();
```

of course

Comment: Thank you very much, you have saved me a lot of time and stress.